# How to install MySQLdb on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, mysql, installation

I'm new to Python and I'm having trouble building MySQLdb, in an attempt to get Google AppEngine SDK running. I have just upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion and have installed the latest XCode (4.4)

I've downloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

```
python setup.py build
```

i get the following output in terminal

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-    2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

both of the following directories exist, i have no idea how to resolve the issue with clang not being able to execute...

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
/usr/local/mysql/include
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that the system is complaining about not be able to find `clang`, which is included in `Command Line Tools` of `Xcode`. Did you installed the tool as well?

Can be installed via

- Open `Xcode`
- Preference (`Command` + `,`)
- `Components` under the `Download` tab

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in a quick and easy way for Mac OS X 10.8:

I assume you have XCode, it's command line tool, Python and MySQL installed.

1. Install PIP:

   ```
   sudo easy_install pip
   ```
2. Edit ~/.profile:

   ```
   nano ~/.profile
   ```

   Copy and paste the following two line

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
   ```

   Save and exit. Afterwords execute the following command

   ```
   source  ~/.profile
   ```
3. Install MySQLdb

   ```
   sudo pip install MySQL-python
   ```

   To test if everything works fine just try

   ```
   python -c "import MySQLdb"
   ```

It worked like a charm for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me except that I used .bash_profile instead of .profile

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not the only thing that you need to do, i check about the cc compiler that is not recognizing, and is not directing to the right file, googling i found that i need to change some files to found it before building, does not stop there, now that its recognizing is not charging the DYDL Libraries... it has been really hard to find a real answer just to start working with python.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it says in the ReadMe to edit site.cfg and put the location of mysql_config in there.