# GCC-4.2 error on Mac OSX Mountain Lion, unable to install mysql-python

Tags: gcc, mysql-python, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having trouble building MySQLdb on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. After upgrading to OSX Mountain Lion from OSX Lion, I have downloaded and installed Xcode 4.4 also. Then, I went to Preference > Downloads of the Xcode and installed Command Line Tools.

I've downloaded MySQL-python ver. 1.2.3 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

When I run

```
python setup.py build
```

I get below message:

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

However, the gcc exists. When I run

```
gcc
```

I get

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
```

Below is a similar question that I have found but its solution, which is exactly what I have done already, doesn't work for me.

[How to install MySQLdb on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787012/how-to-install-mysqldb-on-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've had a similar problem while working with Ruby On Rails 3.2.7.
I too had upgraded the system to Mountain Lion, installed Xcode 4.4.1 and downloaded the Command Line Tools.

On the command line I got an error message saying it was impossible to find the file: `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` (I can't paste the precise output right now, I'm sorry).

I did have a `/usr/bin/gcc` and its version was `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1`

I solved the problem by symlinking the file in the same directory and giving it the name the Ruby script was looking for:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

After that, everything worked fine.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it myself, I believe this should work for all cases - since it's simply giving what the code is looking for.

Comment: I would like to know, if anyone can explain, why the hell is this the case in Mountain Lion?

Comment: I think it mostly depends on how Xcode handles its Command Line Developer Tools, e.g. the way they are deleted when you update Xcode. It is also important how they are packaged into the bundle you download whithin Xcode.

Comment: It seems that the Makefile for Python 2.6 on Mountain Lion specifies CC=gcc-4.2 in a couple of places.

The CONFIG_FLAGS overrides CC as specified in the environment too, which makes re-defining it on the command line impossible. Presumably this is hardcoded to the compiler that built the installed Python, rather than the system compiler.

Modify the two CC definitions in lib/python2.6/config/Makefile and all will be well :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command to make make (or similiar) use the correct gcc:

`export CC=/usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this. For me it was because I installed python from a DMG installer at http://python.org . Those are built against the wrong gcc. I fixed it by compiling python from source using Homebrew: [Link](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install python
```

That links against the correct gcc

(In my specific case I was using an older Python which is why I had used a DMG installer. I discovered that homebrew also has formulas for older versions)

Answer (score 0):

I detoured this problem by using ActivePython.

There's specific installation instruction for MySQLdb [here](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/).

Since this is the first time I've used ActivePython I'm not sure if this' a robust solution for this problem. Therefore, I will leave this question open until I make sure this works.

Comment: I had no problem using this method for a month on two computers.