# library not present in python

Tags: python, mysql

I followed the procedure and installed MySQL for python. When i try to import MySQLdb in python it gives an error.

```
import MySQLdb Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "MySQLdb/init.py", line 19, in import _mysql ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

Comment: What procedure did you follow?

Comment: Verfied? [MySQLdb FAQ](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html)

Comment: followed the procedure here-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833838/gcc-4-2-error-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion-unable-to-install-mysql-python

Answer (score 0):

[set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable so that it includes the path to the MySQL libraries.](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html)

So in your .bash_profile (.bashrc, .profile depends which one you are using) add a line like this one :

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(`/usr/local/mysql/lib` is the path to my MySQL libraries and may differ in your system)

Comment: The issue is not (yet) MySQL client libraries -- it is the Python module itself.

Comment: i did as u said. now getting the following msg-
> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Comment: You probably need to reinstall python-mysql now. There are a number of ways, this answer names a few http://stackoverflow.com/a/5873259/183667.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip for package management and import and then run:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

in your code you should then import the library at the top using:

```
import _mysql
db=_mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="joebob",
              passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
```

See https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst for more details on the package use.

See http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/ for more details on pip.

This is also a great read on best practices for package/environment management 
https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/