# Installing MySQLdb on mac os x

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I am trying to install MySQldb on Mac OS X. But when I run 
    python setup.py build

The terminal shows me this message.

```
sh: mysql_config: command not found
sh: mysql_config: command not found
sh: mysql_config: command not found
sh: mysql_config: command not found
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Dversion_info="(1,2,1,'final',1)" -D__version__="1.2.1"
_mysql.c:39:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include "mysql.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed MySQL on my system. But I don't understand why this is showing. Please kindly will someone help me out.

Comment: try just running `sudo pip install MySQL-python`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787012/how-to-install-mysqldb-on-mountain-lion

Comment: Sorry Nolen I dont have pip. Atleast let me know how to install pip

Comment: Priyank. Please have a look my problem is different than the link you have shared. I have command lines tool for xcode installed and the system is able to find clang but doesn't find "mysql.h"